# Python regex "OR" gives empty string when using findall

Tags: python, regex

I'm using a simple regex `(.*?)(\d+[.]\d+)|(.*?)(\d+)` to match int/float/double value in a string. When doing `findall` the regex shows empty strings in the output. The empty strings gets removed when I remove the `|` operator and do an individual match. I had also tried this on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) it doesn't show any empty string. How can I remove this empty strings ? Here's my code:

```
>>>import re
>>>match_float = re.compile('(.*?)(\d+[.]\d+)|(.*?)(\d+)')
>>>match_float.findall("CA$1.90")  
>>>match_float.findall("RM1")
```

Output:

```
>>>[('CA$', '1.90', '', '')]
>>>[('', '', 'RM', '1')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you defined 4 [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in the pattern, they will always be part of the `re.findall` output unless you remove them (say, by using `filter(None, ...)`.

However, in the current situation, you may "shrink" your pattern to

```
r'(.*?)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZwPJTT/1)

Now, it will only have 2 capturing groups, and thus, `findall` will only output 2 items per tuple in the resulting list.

**Details**:

- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1 matching any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible up to the first occurrence of ...
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Capturing group 2:

  - `\d+` - one of more digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional *non-*capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of a `.` and 1+ digits.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Xd0KYl):

```
import re
rx = r"(.*?)(\d+(?:[.]\d+)?)"
ss = ["CA$1.90", "RM1"]
for s in ss:
    print(re.findall(rx, s))
# => [('CA$', '1.90')]  [('RM', '1')]
```